# How to add date to file upload ios sdk

Tags: php, ios, image, sdk, upload

I have this section of code for my app and was wondering how I would be able to add something unique to the end of the file name such as the date so test.png becomes test16102012.png.

```
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: 
form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\"test.png\"\r\n"]     
dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Thanks

Matt

Comment: Wouldn't be better if the server handled uniqueness?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `stringWithFormat:` method you can add anything in the string itself.

Example:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"filename=\"test%@.png\", @"Some_random_string"];
```

You can also use random generator(`arc4random`) or a `timeIntervalSince1970` method of `NSDate` class.

Hope it helps